# Passing 'event' value from html file to js file

Tags: javascript, html

How to passing 'event' value from html file to js file. because in js, its not defined the event and openFile variable.

Html file:

```
 <form>
     <input type='file' id="poem" accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)' >
 </form>
```

js file:

```
function printPoem(event) {
    var openFile = function(event) {
         var input = event.target;
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function() {
             var text = reader.result;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you tell us more about it i.e. what is going right now at your end? Precisely, you can-not call `openFile(event)` directly from `onhange` event handler (looking at the code you have shared), it should be `onhange='printPoem(event)'`.

Comment: There's no events in files, please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this` from HTML like:

```
<form> <input type='file' id="poem" accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(this)'></form>
```